# UWP Multiple SharePoint List Dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, sharepoint, uwp

So I am working on this project to update SharePoint lists using a UWP app.

I have created one app that successfully updates one SharePoint list without any issues.

This next project required me to split the items up into multiple lists because of the number of objects needed.

However, when I use the same process that I used before, I pretty much get nothing.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DC6Rounds.Pages;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace DC6Rounds
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static object root;

        public static string rooturl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxxx.sharepoint.com,Some-identifier,some-identifier/";
        public string mezzanineurl = rooturl + "lists/426d0dc6-1aa1-45f4-8a5b-0d13dcf918d0/items";
        public string otherurl = rooturl + "lists/294cab78-38c4-4d01-adaa-9194d4fbd049/items";

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            App.SerialNumber = App.Date + "-" + App.Shift;

            var (authResult, message) = await Authentication.AquireTokenAsync();

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                await SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(mezzanineurl, authResult.AccessToken);
                await SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(otherurl, authResult.AccessToken);
            }

            MainSubmitButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            FrameContent.Navigate(typeof(GeneralPage));
            ResultText.Text = "Data Submitted to SharePoint!";
        }

        public async Task<string> SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(string url, string token)
        {
            object root; //ADDED THIS LINE TO MAKE THE CODE WORK.
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                if (url == mezzanineurl)
                {
                    var root = new
                    {
                        fields = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "SerialNumber", App.SerialNumber },
                            { "PDUAlarms", App.PDUAlarms },
                            { "DCPA136Alarms", App.DCPA136Alarms },
                            { "DCPA146Alarms", App.DCPA146Alarms },
                            { "DCPC137Alarms", App.DCPC137Alarms },
                            { "DCPC147Alarms", App.DCPC147Alarms },
                            { "DCPE137Alarms", App.DCPE137Alarms },
                            { "DCPE147Alarms", App.DCPE147Alarms },
                            { "DCPA136Amps", App.DCPA136Amps },
                            { "DCPA146Amps", App.DCPA146Amps },
                            { "DCPC137Amps", App.DCPC137Amps },
                            { "DCPC147Amps", App.DCPC147Amps },
                            { "DCPE137Amps", App.DCPE137Amps },
                            { "DCPE147Amps", App.DCPE147Amps },
                            { "Vesda1Alarms", App.Vesda1Alarms },
                            { "Vesda9Alarms", App.Vesda9Alarms },
                            { "Vesda2Alarms", App.Vesda2Alarms },
                            { "Vesda10Alarms", App.Vesda10Alarms },
                            { "Vesda3Alarms", App.Vesda3Alarms },
                            { "Vesda11Alarms", App.Vesda11Alarms },
                            { "Vesda4Alarms", App.Vesda4Alarms },
                            { "Vesda12Alarms", App.Vesda12Alarms },
                            { "Vesda5Alarms", App.Vesda5Alarms },
                            { "Vesda13Alarms", App.Vesda13Alarms },
                            { "Vesda6Alarms", App.Vesda6Alarms },
                            { "Vesda14Alarms", App.Vesda14Alarms },
                            { "Vesda7Alarms", App.Vesda7Alarms },
                            { "Vesda15Alarms", App.Vesda15Alarms },
                            { "Vesda8Alarms", App.Vesda8Alarms },
                            { "Vesda16Alarms", App.Vesda16Alarms },
                        }
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    var root = new
                    {
                        fields = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { "SerialNumber", App.SerialNumber },
                            { "Notes", App.Notes },
                            { "Z1P1Leaks", App.Z1P1Leaks },
                            { "Z1D1Leaks", App.Z1D1Leaks },
                            { "Z1P5Leaks", App.Z1P5Leaks },
                            { "Z1P3Leaks", App.Z1P3Leaks },
                            { "Z1P4Leaks", App.Z1P4Leaks },
                            { "Z3P2Leaks", App.Z3P2Leaks },
                            { "AirCompressorLeaks", App.AirCompressorLeaks },
                            { "Z3P4Leaks", App.Z3P4Leaks },
                            { "Z3P1Leaks", App.Z3P1Leaks },
                            { "Z3P3Leaks", App.Z3P3Leaks },
                            { "Z2P1Leaks", App.Z2P1Leaks },
                            { "Z1P2Leaks", App.Z1P2Leaks },
                            { "PreactionLog", App.PreactionLog },
                            { "FirePanelAlarms", App.FirePanelAlarms },
                            { "Car1Inspection", App.Car1Inspection },
                            { "Car1Operational", App.Car1Operational },
                            { "Car2Inspection", App.Car2Inspection },
                            { "Car2Operational", App.Car2Operational },
                            { "Date", App.Date },
                            { "Day", App.Day },
                            { "Shift", App.Shift },
                            { "Engineer", App.Engineer },
                            { "TimeStarted", App.TimeStarted },
                            { "EquipmentSummary", App.EquipmentSummary },
                            { "BMSAlarms", App.BMSAlarms },
                            { "OAT", App.OAT },
                        }
                    };
                }

                var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, s);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return responseString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One Class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DC6Rounds
{
    class MezzanineListItems
    {
        public class Lookup
        {
            public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return SerialNumber;
            }
        }

        public class Value
        {
            public Lookup fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fields
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
            public string ODdataETag { get; set; }

            public string PDUAlarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPA136Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPA146Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPC137Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPC147Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPE137Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPE147Alarms { get; set; }
            public string DCPA136Amps { get; set; }
            public string DCPA146Amps { get; set; }
            public string DCPC137Amps { get; set; }
            public string DCPC147Amps { get; set; }
            public string DCPE137Amps { get; set; }
            public string DCPE147Amps { get; set; }
            public string Vesda1Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda9Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda2Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda10Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda3Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda11Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda4Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda12Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda5Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda13Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda6Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda14Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda7Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda15Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda8Alarms { get; set; }
            public string Vesda16Alarms { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
            public string ODataContext { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
            public string ODdataETag { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("fields@odata.context")]
            public string FieldsODataContext { get; set; }

            public Fields fields { get; set; }

            public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Other Class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DC6Rounds
{
    class OtherListItems
    {
        public class Lookup
        {
            public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return SerialNumber;
            }
        }

        public class Value
        {
            public Lookup fields { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fields
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
            public string ODdataETag { get; set; }

            public string Notes { get; set; }
            public string Z1P1Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z1D1Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z1P5Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z1P3Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z1P4Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z3P2Leaks { get; set; }
            public string AirCompressorLeaks { get; set; }
            public string Z3P4Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z3P1Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z3P3Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z2P1Leaks { get; set; }
            public string Z1P2Leaks { get; set; }
            public string PreactionLog { get; set; }
            public string FirePanelAlarms { get; set; }
            public string Car1Inspection { get; set; }
            public string Car1Operational { get; set; }
            public string Car2Inspection { get; set; }
            public string Car2Operational { get; set; }
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public string Day { get; set; }
            public string Shift { get; set; }
            public string Engineer { get; set; }
            public string TimeStarted { get; set; }
            public string EquipmentSummary { get; set; }
            public string BMSAlarms { get; set; }
            public string OAT { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
            public string ODataContext { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("@odata.etag")]
            public string ODdataETag { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("fields@odata.context")]
            public string FieldsODataContext { get; set; }

            public Fields fields { get; set; }

            public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the issue that my classes are using the same names?  I'm not getting any build errors, so I was not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Added the SubmitButton_Click code for added clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems the problem is how I setup "root"

I had to add "object root;" at the beginning of public async Task SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(string url, string token)

"root" was never getting out of the if statement.